# BaseHttpRequestHandler set global values

Tags: python, class, load, instance, basehttprequesthandler

i got a little problem here, this class  here:

```
class Skynet(SkynetServer):
def __init__(self):
    self.SkynetStatus = False

    SkynetServer.__init__(self)


def skynet_server_start(self):
    if not self.skynet and self.server_status:
        self.skynet = True
        self.skynet_process = Process(target=self.skynet_start)
        self.skynet_process.start()
    else: print("Start Server first!")

def skynet_server_stop(self):
    self.skynet = False
    self.skynet_stop()
```

is calling this little on:

```
class SkynetServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
def do_GET(self):
    self._set_headers()
    if self.path == "/":
        self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>".encode("utf-8"))
    if self.path == "chunk":
        print(self.SkynetStatus)
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    return

class SkynetServer():
def __init__(self):
    self.httpd = None

def skynet_start(self):
    host = '192.168.178.31'
    port = 23575
    httpd = HTTPServer((host, port), SkynetServer_RequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

so my question here is: how can i use the self.SkynetStatus value from Skyne instance in requesthandler?
dont know how to load it....
hope you guys know what i mean ;)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem in another way =)